# parallelizing sum with indices

Tags: matlab

Sorry ahead that the title may not be precise. But I am just not sure what it should be called.

Consider an index vector id=[1,1,2] and a data vector d=[3,4,5]. I would like to have

```
A(id)=A(id)+d;
```

Of course, I am aware that this is invalid. Just wonder if there is an efficient way (avoiding for loop) if length(id)=length(d) is very long.

To be more precise, I want to have

```
for ii=1:length(id)
  A(id(ii))=A(id(ii))+d(ii);
end
```

So for the example above, I expect A = [3+4,5] = [7,5].

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) :

```
A = accumarray(id(:), d);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, maybe I should just expand to another dimension trading off space with time.

```
dummy=zeros(max(id),length(d));
dummy(sub2ind(size(dummy),id,1:length(d)))=d;
A=sum(dummy,2);
```